# Initialize an inherited class

Tags: c#, class, initialization

I have a class (let's call it Class1), which inherits another class (Class2).
What I'm trying to do is run the costructor method in Class2 upon inheritance in Class1.

I suppose it has to look something like this:

```
// Class1
public class Class1 : Class2
{
    public Class1()
    {

    }
}
// Class2
public class Class2
{
    public Class2()
    {
        //this is the function I want to run
    }
}
```

But I can't get it to work like this.
Is there a way to do this, without actually having to call the Class2() constructor method from Class1?

Comment: constructors aren't methods, or functions, they're just constructors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're declaring your constructors incorrectly.  Remove the `void` keyword:

```
// Class1 
public class Class1 : Class2 
{ 
    public Class1() 
    { 

    } 
} 
// Class2 
public class Class2 
{ 
    public Class2() 
    { 
        //this is the function I want to run 
    } 
}
```

The default constructor of the base class will run automatically.  If you wish to call a non-default constructor, you can do it like this:

```
// Class1 
public class Class1 : Class2 
{ 
    public Class1() : base("argument")
    { 

    } 
} 
// Class2 
public class Class2 
{ 
    public Class2() 
    { 
    } 
    public Class2(string theParameter)
    {
        //code for initializing the object with the string parameter 
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, that's how i had it in my code. i simply added them here without thinking. But it's not working for me either way.

Comment: @GabiBarrientos how do you know it's not working?  The code you posted (with the `void` keywords) won't compile.  Is your code failing to compile, or is it compiling but not working as you expect?

Comment: because i tried to run Debug.WriteLine("test"); in Class2's constructor. but using the second piece of code you wrote down actually works for me. thanks. I will be accepting this as my answer, but i need to wait for a couple of minutes

Answer (score 0):

You always call `Class2`'s constructor. If you don't have code calling `base()` it's added for you. If `Class2` doesn't have a parameterless constructor, and you don't explicitly call the base constructor, you get an compile error.

If you have a `Class1` you must have had a `Class2` constructed; you can't have a `C_Sharp_Developer` without having `Person` first.

Comment: The first paragraph should end with "... you get a compiler error."  (And, come to think of it, the condition should be "if `Class2` doesn't have an *accessible* parameterless constructor...")

Comment: @phoog I changed the "compile error" bit, because that's what I meant to write. I'll leave the point about accessibility so your comment can stand as your thinking of it when I didn't ;)